# Custom fonts don't load in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-font

Custom fonts don't load in Xamarin iOS. As described in the Xamarin documentation from 2013 (https://blog.xamarin.com/custom-fonts-in-ios/), I have done the following:

1) Import the font into Resources
2) Set Build Action to "BundleResource" (mistake in the Xamarin documentation)
3) Copy to output directory: "Always Copy"
4) Added the font name to the array "Fonts provided by application" in the Info.plist (making the font available in the storyboard, but not at runtime)

In FinishedLaunching() in the App Delegate, I iterate through all installed fonts:

```
foreach (var family in UIFont.FamilyNames)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{family}");

    foreach (var names in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(family))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{names}");
    }
}
var fontName = UIFont.FromName("Karbon", 20.0f); // fontName is null
```

No custom fonts show up, what is the problem here?

---

Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac (Preview)
Version 7.1 Preview (7.1 build 1178)
Runtime: Mono 5.2.0.179 (2017-04/4498dc4) (64-bit)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 10.12.0.5 (Visual Studio Community)

Comment: Have you edited your `plist`?

Comment: I have also added the array "Fonts provided by application" in the Info.plist and added the font, which makes the font available in the storyboard. However, at runtime, the font is not loaded.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here for Windows 10 and Visual Studio

- put `xxx.ttf` in Resources folder
- Right Click on `xxx.ttf` > Properties > Build Action: BundleResource
- don't do => Copy to output directory: Always Copy
- **Xamarin.iOS > Right-click on `info.plist` > Open With > Xml (Text) Editor**
- Add following:

```
<dict>

    ... ... ...

    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>xxx.ttf</string>
    </array>

    ... ... ...

</dict>
```

- **in xaml use Typeface name instead of `xxx.ttf` file name (double click `xxx.ttf` to see Typeface name)**

```
<Label.FontFamily>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Typeface_name" />
        <On Platform="Android" Value="filename_name.ttf#Typeface_name" />
        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/filename_name.ttf#Typeface_name" />
    </OnPlatform>
</Label.FontFamily>
```

Comment: Thank you - despite reading several references on this with just a bare string after the UIAppFonts key, it wasn't until I put the single value in an array that I go this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the Info.plist has to be updated (including the font type, e.g. ttf) and the Font’s properties should be set to not copy to output directory (Do not copy). It works after these changes.